How to calculate.list all DSO's < mag10 visible from my given location/time (Python)
I've got a EVScope and a working knowledge of Python and either the EVScope app doens't give me enough content/variety of objects to observe or deskktop software focusses too heavily on nebula/stars when I'm really only interested in more "interesting" DSOs like galaxies etc.
I'm trying to get my head around how I can build a program given my location/time and a list of objects with mag and RA/Dec that will then display whatever is visible at that time.
In my head I can visualise a point on the earth (me) with a half-sphere with me in the center of the base and the various objects locatyed on the sphere which is all those visible DSOs but I'm just not sure where to start.
Step one is clearly local sidereal time but the next part is a failure of theory and terminology on my part. Hoping someone can provide some pointers to help me get to next steps.

Not an answer to the actual question, however: did you try creating a list of observable objects with sth. like Stellarium? It offers you to choose your types of objects, your limiting magnitude, your FOV limits, your time-of-day... and you can likely link it also to your telescope to actually use it as your one-stop interface.

Most people just use an existing planetarium program to browse around.  But you can compute the Alt/Az of each object, and anything with an Alt > 0 is visible from your location.  This page offers a few different ways to do that: https://www.celestialprogramming.com/convert_ra_dec_to_alt_az.html
